# Create directory using Gradle on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a Gradle buildscript which works fine locally but on our Jenkins CI environment it seems to work incorrect.

In the gradle file i have a statement that creates a directory:

```
dockerBuildDir = mkdir("${buildDir}/docker")
```

This works fine locally but when I execute the build script on a Jenkins machine this directory is not created (I do not get an error message!). I think this is related to the workspace or something but cannot find the cause of the problem.

Any hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding --info, --debug or --stacktrace to capture more debugging information?

Comment: The problem is that the ```gradle clean task2``` creates the directory when initialising and the clean tasks deletes them. I reordered the script and it works now!